# How to mark item in listView readable while scrolling?

Tags: android, listview

I am building my first application. It is just a list of server alarms received by a text message (SMS). There is just a list view action (no details on click). I want to be possible to mark items read just by reading them. When I open my app, I see messages ordered from old to new and my listView position is set to the bottom of the listView. When I will scroll up, the displayed items i want to mark as read.

And I did it like this:

```
public class AlertsListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, AlertsContract.PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        adapter = new AlertAdapter(context, R.layout.row, c, from, to, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setSelected(listView.getCount());

        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i &lt; firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; i++) {
                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor)view.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlertsContract._ID));
                    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlertsContract.TYPE));
                    Log.d("VIEWED", "This is viewed "+ type + " id: " + id);

                    // here I can get the id and mark the item read
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I think, that this is not the best solution. One problem is that if the user is not going to scroll the list, no items are marked as viewed even the user could see at least 3 - 4 items from the list.

Is there any event for a listView item like "displayed" or something like this? Some event that will occur every time the listView item gets to the visible area of listView?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use your adapter's `getView` method. ([Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29))

It's called every time when your `ListView` tries to display an item.

But be careful, it's also called when the item is not fully displayed, so you should check this again, perhaps with the solution in your onScroll method.