# How to mark ListView items as `read` once shown for a few seconds?

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to mark newly added items to my list with **bold**. And once user seen this item (i.e. it was shown on the screen for 3 seconds), I would like to mark it as read (i.e. remove **bold**). I know how to mark some items with bold. But how to catch the event when user seen the item?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832203/how-to-mark-item-in-listview-readable-while-scrolling) is quite close to what I am looking for. But it has no accepted answer. And it is not quite clear how to wait for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Your adapter has a getView().
- Your adapter has a data source (a list, content provider, etc. of
  some sort).
- Your adapter knows which position(s) are visible (because the list
  asked for those).
- Combined with an OnScrollListener, you can tell when the list is
  moving.
- If you use a view holder pattern (and you should) in your adapter,
  you can tell when views are being reused.
- You can also set a 3 sec timer that will "flag" the items as read, as
  long as they remain visible.
- You can tell if an item is visible by asking the list
  ([getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) and the [last](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) counterpart).

That's a starting point.

Comment: good answer, but it seems we don't need onscrolllistener. check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start a Thread on your getView method.

> 1. check if item is read.
> 2. if not, set an identifier as tag for the view.
> 3. start your thread.
> 4. after for ex. 4 sec sleep. check if that view tag still equal to the identifier.
> 5. if yes change view style. and set item as read in your data structure.

email.xml (item layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EMail.java (item class):

```
public class EMail {

    public String title;
    public boolean read;

    public EMail(String title, boolean read) {
        this.title = title;
        this.read = read;
    }
}
```

Activity onCreate Method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ListAdapter emails = new ListAdapter(this, 0, new ArrayList<EMail>());
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 1", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 2", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 3", true));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 4", true));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 5", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 6", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 7", true));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 8", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 9", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 10", true));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 11", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 12", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 13", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 14", true));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 15", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 16", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 17", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 18", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 19", false));
        emails.add(new EMail("Email 20", false));

        lv.setAdapter(emails);
    }
```

Adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EMail> {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int identifier = 0;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            ArrayList<EMail> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.email, null);
        }

        final int id = identifier++;
        v.setTag(id);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final LinearLayout back = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.background);
        final EMail e = getItem(position);

        titleTextView.setText(e.title);

        if (e.read)
            back.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
        else
        {
            back.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

            final View view = v;

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    if (view.getTag().toString().equals(id+""))
                    {
                        e.read = true;
                        ((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                back.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            timer.schedule(task, 3000);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to your ListView and check when user scrolls to your new items.